# Как проверить находится ли точка в произвольном многоугольнике?

Tags: c++, геометрия

Пример

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как проверить находится ли точка в произвольном многоугольнике?
Имеется спрайт произвольвольного многоугольника, может быть как и правильной формы так и неправильной( к примуре описывающий символ бесконечности и т.д.
есть ли какая нибудь универсальная формула?
математическая или на любом из яп(желательно с++).

Comment: Как задан многоугольник? Набором вершин? Картинкой?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy
Набором вершин, 2д пространство

Comment: @Harry не могу нарисовать, это зоны нажатия мышки, они невидимые.

Comment: Проведите из точки луч в любом направлении (удобно горизонтальный вправо), пересеките его со всеми сторонами многоугольника (требуется аккуратность если луч прошёл через вершину), если число пересечение нечётно - вы внутри. Сложность - линейная от числа вершин/сторон. Если надо быстрее, можно сделать за логарифм. Но это сложно.

Comment: Если хотите в ответе увидеть линейный алгоритм, добавьте в вопрос структуры данных с которыми вы работаете. Ещё лучше если вы добавите в вопрос вашу попытку решить задачу.

Comment: ваше решение про лучи работать не будет если фигура впуклая. решения нет, это набор "случайных" последовательных точек которые замыкают фигуру по контору, ( с месяцем ваше решение не будет работать так как лучи будут идти по зоне которая находится вне фигуры

Comment: Добавил пример фигур

Comment: Решение про лучи работает для многоугольников любой формы. Читайте внимательнее: "если число пересечений нечётное, мы внутри".